# Errors with Android studio?

Tags: java, android

When I install **android studio** I get these errors:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDnaS.png]

and

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4iIA.png]

I set up an emulator but the error is still happening.    This is the first time I'm using android studio.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to **File** -> **Project Structure** and check, you have any module and your sdk path is correct.

[image]

[image]